# Switch to host desktop from citrix session

Tags: fullscreen, citrix

How can I leave the fullscreen mode of a citrix session and return to the host desktop (Ubuntu)?

I am using the [Citrix Receiver for Linux](http://www.citrix.com/downloads/citrix-receiver/legacy-receiver-for-linux/receiver-for-linux-13-2.html) package.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two steps are needed for this.

1. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in the citrix session. This enables keyboard shortcuts from the host system (Ubuntu).
2. Now you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch the focus to the application you used before opening citrix (or the desktop).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a shortcut to return the keyboard control to the Citrix session immediately?

Comment: This doesn't work for me Ubuntu 20x

Comment: Used to work. Stopped working for me around March 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Just extending the answer as I've been recently dealing with the topic...

In Ubuntu 17.10 with ica-client 13.8

1. As indicated above, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> enables passing key sequences to the host system for a few seconds. After a certain amount of time, keyboard shortcuts are passed back to the citrix desktop.
2. <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> exactly as described above, i.e. switch focus to applications you were using before, but does not allow to switch/see the host Desktop (e.g. Gnome).
3. If you need to launch new applications, you need access the Ubuntu desktop, which you can achieve with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
4. During the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> time window, you may use any other shortcut, e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will open a terminal.

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds to the existing accepted answer to the original question. The question isn't about [Ubuntu keyboard shortcuts...](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts)

Comment: Well... it would have saved me (probably a fairly thick bloke) some time, particularly how to get hold of the desktop. Note that in windows shift+f2 directly shows the desktop, which is not the case in Ubuntu, I was wrongly expecting the same behaviour. Happy about the moderator deleting it, if it's deemed useless... cheers!