# Prevent application from processing keyboard shortcut

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, workspaces, citrix

In Ubuntu 20.04 (using Gnome 3), I have the keyboard shortcut for switching desktop workspaces (distinguishing because the software I'm using is also called "Workspace") set to `Ctrl+Alt+Up/Down`. This works great except for when I connect to a Citrix Workspace VM in fullscreen mode. Citrix Workspace takes all keypresses and processes them in the guest instance. What I would like to do is prevent Citrix Workspace (and any other app if possible) from processing these keychords so I can have Citrix Workspace fullscreen on its own desktop workspace, but still switch between desktop workspaces using my keyboard shortcut. The alternative is to "un-fullscreen" and then switch desktop workspaces, as Citrix Workspace does not steal keyboard focus like this in windowed mode.

Is there any way to force Gnome to process certain keychords without passing them onto child applications? Or alternatively, is there a way within Citrix Workspace to prevent fullscreen mode from stealing focus for global shortcuts as if it were in windowed mode?

Comment: On KDE, it's possible to maximize and remove title bars, which is effectively like using full screen without the input capture.  It's also possible to move apps to the desktop, so it's like they're replacing the background wallpaper.  Maybe there is a way to do something similar with GNOME?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to force fullscreen Citrix to always ignore certain keyboard shortcuts, but here's a useful workaround:

Within a Citrix fullscreen session, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> will pass (some? all? not sure) keyboard shortcuts through to the host OS, i.e. Ubuntu, for a short time. I use it for Super+Tab to switch app windows, and I confirmed that it works for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>.

See [Switch to host desktop from citrix session](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744672/switch-to-host-desktop-from-citrix-session).

Comment: Crap, I couldn't post this as an answer right away and forgot to come back and update it. I found this a few hours after I posted which worked. I can tell you that it does not capture the Windows key after hitting `Ctrl+F2` which is *usually* a decent indicator it's not capturing or stopping guest-specific inputs. I also found that a fullscreen app/desktop gives `Ctrl+F2` behavior if you use the kb passthru mode and switch between the desktop workspaces using your configured "Switch Workspace" command. `Alt+tab`ing to the Citrix workspace however will return all focus to Citrix.

Comment: I tested the above on `gnome3` and `lightdm`. Not sure about other DEs like KDE.